# List Windows Updates using browser

Tags: php, javascript, windows, browser

I'm facing a problem with my system and I figured out that it's caused by a MS Update. Since there are some users that can't find, or even don't know how to uninstall the update, I dediced to create a compatibility test page, where I'm going to check some info about the user's PC, like web browser version, **installed windows updates (the most important!)** and Stuff. I remember that Windows XP was able to search and install the system updated using the Web Browser.

Does anybody knows how can I list the installed updates using PHP ou JavaScript maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be kind of terrifying if the server's PHP could access my computer.

Comment: js\php on some random site having access to the registry on my pc, haven't thought this through have you.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc and Dagon yes, of course I didn't think that PHP could itself and ALONE access my PC data! As sdleihssirhc said, that would be terrifying! But making PHP work with a kind of ActiveX or something similar doesn't seems to be a bad idea! (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this without an ActiveX control.  The browser does not have direct access to the registry, which is where the information you need lives.

Answer (score 0):

The browser itself(i.e http request headers) won't give u enough information.

Either way, your client need to run some local code with higher privilege.